How to access internationalization in server actions
I've implemented internationalization in my Next.js 14 application following the official guide provided here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization. The setup works well, enabling me to access internationalization in both server and client components via URL parameters. However, I've encountered an issue with integrating it into server actions.
Specifically, I'm using a server action that employs zod for validation. This action validates form inputs and returns error messages. Now, I need to integrate the internationalization system to provide locale-specific error messages.
Here's an excerpt from the Next.js documentation illustrating the server action setup:
'use server'
 
import { z } from 'zod'
 
const schema = z.object({
  email: z.string({
    invalid_type_error: 'Invalid Email', // <-- Need to integrate internationalization here
  }),
})
 
export default async function createUser(formData: FormData) {
  const validatedFields = schema.safeParse({
    email: formData.get('email'),
  })
 
  // Return early if the form data is invalid
  if (!validatedFields.success) {
    return {
      errors: validatedFields.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
    }
  }
 
  // Mutate data
}

Despite thorough research, I couldn't find a solution to integrate internationalization seamlessly into server actions. I'd appreciate any insights or guidance on how to achieve this effectively. Thank you!

I have struggled with the same problem and finaly found the solution.
I am using https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app package, which is also mentioned in NextJS docs. And here is the workaround for using in server actions https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/blog/translations-outside-of-react-components#the-exception-that-proves-the-rule
I prefer to use NEXT_LOCALE cookie to store per-request locale. So my i18n file looks like:
//i18n.ts
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';
import {cookies} from "next/headers";

export default getRequestConfig(async () => {
    // here is the recognition of clients locale
    const locale = cookies().get('NEXT_LOCALE')?.value ?? 'ua';

    return {
        locale,
        messages: (await import(`../messages/${locale}.json`)).default
    };
});

Then, in server action file use it like


import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server';

export async function someAction(input) {
    const t = await getTranslations();
    return t('common.some_message'),
}



And for your problem I see two possible solutions:

Put you schema inside the server action function and use translation directly in schema
In your schema provide error messages as a valid json paths to your translation messages, then in server action function map through all errors and add translations. For example



'use server'

import { z } from 'zod'
import { getTranslations } from 'next-intl/server';

const schema = z.object({
    email: z.string({
        invalid_type_error: 'user.creation.invalid_email',
    }),
})

export default async function createUser(formData: FormData) {
    const validatedFields = schema.safeParse({
        email: formData.get('email'),
    })

    // Return early if the form data is invalid
    if (!validatedFields.success) {
        const t = await getTranslations();
        return {
            errors: validatedFields.error.errors.map(e => {
                return t(e.message); // or structure wherever you need
            }),
        };
    }
}




a short name that will correspond to your dictionary file
import { z } from 'zod'
 
const schema = z.object({
  email: z
    .string({
      required_error: "emailrequired",
      invalid_type_error: "invalidemail",
    })
    .email({
      message: "invalidemail"
    })
    .trim()
    .toLowerCase()
})

dictionaries/en.json
{
  "emailrequired": "Required email address",
  "invalidemail": "Invalid email address"
}

dictionaries/tr.json
{
  "emailrequired": "E-posta gerekli",
  "invalidemail": "Geçersiz e-posta adresi"
}

where you want to view the message:
import { createUser } from "lib/actions";
import { useActionState } from "react";

function signup({ dictionary }: { dictionary: { [key: string]: string }; }) {
  const [state, action, pending] = useActionState(createUser, undefined);
  return (
    <form action={action}>
     //form fields
     //errors
     {state?.errors?.email && (
       {state.errors.email.map((error: string, index: number) => (
         <p key={index}>{dictionary[error]}</p>
       ))}
     )}
    </form>
  )
}

export default signup

